# Type-C to Type-C cable with DP on MacBook Pro 16" 2019 doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) and [MSI Monitor MAG274QRF-QD](https://www.msi.com/Monitor/Optix-MAG274QRF-QD). I want to connect them with Type-C to Type-C cable, but it doesn't work. I've tried cable USB 3.2 Gen 2 last time but it still just black screen on monitor and just power delivery works.
Does anybody have any suggestion what can help me?

Comment: Have you tried any resolution or Hz adjustments on the monitor itself when it is connected? Many USBC cables are just fine for power delivery, but [this cable from Apple](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ4H2AM/A/) supports all the requirements: _USB 3.1 Gen 2 data transfer up to 10 Gbps, DisplayPort video output (HBR3), and charging up to 100W._

Answer (score 1):

So, my bad. Original Apple Thunderbolt 3 cable works fine.